# Format for a JPA query containing an aggregation and subquery?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I have the following entity (some columns omitted for brevity):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "INSTRUCTION")
public class Instruction {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, unique = true)
    public Long id;

    @Column(name = "CURRENT_STATUS", nullable = false)
    private InstructionState currentStatus;

    @Column(name = "SUBTYPE", nullable = false)
    private InstructionAction subtype;

    //Getters & Setters
}
```

I want to write the following query in JPA to retrieve a count of the instructions grouped by their `CURRENT_STATUS` and `SUBTYPE`. I know that the following SQL works:

```
SELECT CURRENT_STATUS, SUBTYPE, COUNT(*) count 
FROM (SELECT ID, CURRENT_STATUS, SUBTYPE 
        FROM INSTRUCTION 
        WHERE VALUE_DATE= '17-JUN-21'  
        AND LAST_UPDATED >= '16-JUN-21' 
        AND LAST_UPDATED < '17-JUN-21' 
        GROUP BY ID, CURRENT_STATUS, SUBTYPE)
GROUP BY CURRENT_STATUS, SUBTYPE;
```

I want to take the result from this query and map it to a new object call `InstructionCount`:

```
public class InstructionCount {

    private InstructionState status;
    private InstructionAction subType;
    private Integer count;

    public InstructionCount(final InstructionState status, final InstructionAction subType, final Integer count) {
        this.status = status;
        this.subType = subType;
        this.count = count;
    }

    //Getters and setters
}
```

**The Problem**

I have come up with the following query in JPA for this in my repository class:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new com.modles.InstructionCount(CURRENT_STATUS status, SUBTYPE subType, COUNT(*) count) \n" +
            "FROM (SELECT ID, CURRENT_STATUS, SUBTYPE \n" +
            "\t\tFROM LTD_RTGS_CASHINSTRUCTION \n" +
            "\t\tWHERE VALUE_DATE= :valueDate  \n" +
            "\t\tAND LAST_UPDATED >= :lastUpdatedFrom \n" +
            "\t\tAND LAST_UPDATED < :lastUpdatedTo \n" +
            "\t\tGROUP BY ID, CURRENT_STATUS, SUBTYPE)\n" +
            "GROUP BY CURRENT_STATUS, SUBTYPE", nativeQuery = true)
    List<InstructionCount> findInstructionCounts(@Param("valueDate") LocalDate valueDate, @Param("lastUpdatedFrom") LocalDateTime lastUpdatedFrom, @Param("lastUpdatedTo") LocalDateTime lastUpdatedTo);
```

The issue is that this does not work, and I have found it is because I cannot use the approach of mapping it to a new object using the `SELECT new com.modles.InstructionCount` with `nativeQuery = true`. However when I try to remove the `nativeQuery = true` part and run my test I get the following error:

[image]

I also notice that the SQL gets syntax errors in the IDE, highlighted on the second SELECT statement, so I presume there is an issue with this format when not using nativeQuery.

Can anyone help with how I can resolve this issue? I know this can work, because when I remove the `SELECT new com.modles.InstructionCount` part, it will just return a list of `Object[]` with the correct values I'm expecting, but I would much prefer to map this to the correct object as part of the query. Alternatively, if there is a way to write this query using the Specification API, I would also use that approach!

Comment: first of all why do you need inner select query?

Comment: your query should be just
SELECT CURRENT_STATUS, SUBTYPE, COUNT(ID)  
FROM INSTRUCTION 
        WHERE VALUE_DATE= '17-JUN-21'  
        AND LAST_UPDATED >= '16-JUN-21' 
        AND LAST_UPDATED < '17-JUN-21' 
GROUP BY CURRENT_STATUS, SUBTYPE;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below query should just work just fine and there is no need of your inner/sub query

```
SELECT CURRENT_STATUS, SUBTYPE, COUNT(ID)  
FROM INSTRUCTION 
        WHERE VALUE_DATE= '17-JUN-21'  
        AND LAST_UPDATED >= '16-JUN-21' 
        AND LAST_UPDATED < '17-JUN-21' 
GROUP BY CURRENT_STATUS, SUBTYPE;
```

This should works seemlessly while returning the result as

InstructionCount

------->Edit------------->

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new com.modles.InstructionCount(currentStatus, subtype, count(id)) FROM Instruction WHERE valueDate= :valueDate AND lastUpdatedFrom >= :lastUpdatedFrom AND lastUpdatedTo < :lastUpdatedTo GROUP BY id, currentStatus, subtype")
    List<InstructionCount> findInstructionCounts(@Param("valueDate") LocalDate valueDate, @Param("lastUpdatedFrom") LocalDateTime lastUpdatedFrom, @Param("lastUpdatedTo") LocalDateTime lastUpdatedTo);
```

Comment: Oh wow I never noticed that, brilliant, thanks very much. So that simplifies the query greatly, but I still have the issue where if I copy this query into a `@Query` annotation, I still get syntax errors unless I use `nativeQuery=true`. Do you know how I change this query to fit the expected syntax so it doesn't have to be a native query?

Comment: you should add the fieldnames from the Entity class not the column names from DB.
If you add column names from DB like "CURRENT_STATUS, SUBTYPE"  it expects it to be nativeQuery=true.  so your fields should be from the Entity Java Class like SELECT currentStatus, subtype, COUNT(id)